# How to add node to front of linked list C++? I'm overthinking the concept

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add a node to the front of my linked list in C++. I have developed code for adding to the end of the list, which is easier for my brain to comprehend than the latter. Here is my code:


**The class**

```
 struct ListNode
    {
       double value;
       ListNode *next;
       ListNode(double value1, ListNode *next1 = NULL)
       {
          value = value1;
          next = next1;
       }      
    };
    ListNode *head;                   // List head pointer
```

**The function that adds to the end of the list**

```
void LinkedList::add(double number)
{
   if (head == NULL)
      head = new ListNode(number);
   else
     {
       // The list is not empty
       // Use nodePtr to traverse the list
       ListNode *nodePtr = head;
       while (nodePtr->next != NULL)
          nodePtr = nodePtr->next;

       // nodePtr->next is NULL so nodePtr points to the last node
       // Create a new node and put it after the last node
       nodePtr->next = new ListNode(number);
     }
}
```

I'm just having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around moving all the pointers around for adding to the beginning.

Thanks.

Comment: Drawing the nodes and links and pointer often helps focus the mind.

Comment: Adding a new node to the front of a linked list is a lot easier than adding it to the end of the list, especially in a single-linked list that doesn't have a `tail` pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the beginning is simpler than doing it at the end.

You need to set the tail of the new node to the current head, and set the head to the new node.

```
head = new ListNode(number, head);
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely was making this more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the beginning is simple.  Don't make things more complicated.

```
ListNode * new_node = new ListNode(number);
if (head == nullptr)
{
  head = new_node;
}
else
{
  // Make the new node point to the (old) head.
  new_node->next = head;

  // Make the head pointer point to the new node.
  head = new_node;
}
```

Use pencil (or pen) and paper and draw the pointers and nodes as you step through both cases.

---

Case 1: Empty list

Before insertion:

```
head --> nullptr
```

After insertion:

```
             +-----+  
new_node --> | 25  |  
             +-----+
```

```
             +-----+  
new_node --> | 25  |  
             +-----+  
                ^  
                |  
head -----------+
```

---

Case 2: Not empty list

Before insertion:

```
         +-----+  
head --> | 36  |  
         +-----+
```

After insertion:

```
             +-----+  
new_node --> | 25  |  
             +-----+
```

```
             +-----+      +-----+  
new_node --> | 25  |  --> | 36  |
             +-----+      +-----+   
                             ^  
                             |  
head ------------------------+
```

```
             +-----+      +-----+  
new_node --> | 25  |  --> | 36  |
             +-----+      +-----+   
                ^  
                |  
head -----------+
```

---

*Per Remy's comment, the above can be simplified to:*

```
ListNode * new_node = new ListNode(number);

// Make the new node point to the (old) head.
new_node->next = head;

// Make the head pointer point to the new node.
head = new_node;
```

Or simply:

```
// Make the new node point to the (old) head, and
// make the head pointer point to the new node.
head = new ListNode(number, head);
```

Comment: "*Don't make things more complicated*" - You don't need to check the current `head` for nullptr since you are going to overwrite it anyway, so just use it as-is: `ListNode * new_node = new ListNode(number); new_node->next = head; head = new_node;`  which can be simplified to just `head = new ListNode(number, head);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  Thanks, added the simplification.  The original may be easier to understand by beginners.

Comment: This was also a great answer, I appreciate the images as well